# NGINX 404 error despite Magento Installation complete on CentOS 7 terminal

Tags: magento-community, composer, nginx, centos, mariadb

I am trying to load the /admin part of my development build of the website. I am unsure what could be the cause of this.

Using this command: (Some of these details are intentionally not in line with our actual configuration)

```
bin/magento setup:install \
--base-url=http://localhost/ \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=root \
--db-password='password' \
--backend-frontname=admin \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com.au \
--admin-user='admin' \
--admin-password='password' \
--language=en_US \
--currency=AUD \
--timezone=Australia/Sydney \
--use-rewrites=1
```

I want to be able to use the Magento admin panel as described on my CentOS 7 terminal window.

```
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin
Nothing to import.
```

I came to this result after following [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html) on the nginx section of this documentation. However, I seem to be getting to this page when I went onto my browser window:

> The page you are looking for is not found.

As a form of troubleshooting, I have gone through `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` but I am unsure what the proper values are supposed to be in server_name. I have currently appointed the value currently to `127.0.0.1:8080` while listening to port `80` (potential answer...?)

Here is my current setup so far:

- centos 7
- nginx/1.12.2
- php/7.2.16
- mariadb/10.3.13 (mysql 15.1)
- magento 2.3 community edition
- composer/1.8.4
- apache/2.4.6

I'm primarily trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy for apache so that it can support higher traffic volumes and still be able to utilize the .htaccess  file (and retain functionality opportunities of the apache system).

This is a development environment, so I am willing to try experimental changes onto this server.

The `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is currently empty.

I know for sure that I am not implementing this properly so any ideas, comments or suggestions will much be appreciated.

Comment: do you have all modules loaded into apache? like `rewrite`

Comment: also use either apache or nginx, and install varnish for high traffic...

Comment: Rewrite module is working as intended as `AH01574: module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping` indicates this.

It looks like I will install Varnish instead of nginx to support higher traffic.
How does varnish compare to NGINX?

Comment: apache and nginx are both just web servers, varnish - is a full page cache in memory.

Comment: after struggling to install and run varnish and on nginx, I just decided to work with apache.